# How to add '&' functionality to run program in background in dummy shell?

Tags: c, shell, command-line, background

I know I have to fork() but what do I do after that?  Also I know I have to skip a wait() call at some point but how do I implement that?  When I type '&' after a command it says "cannot access &: No such file or directory".  The dummy shell should return a prompt for users immediately for more command input if the & is typed after a program and its parameters (Because the program will be running in the background).  How do I accomplish this?

Here is the code I'm pretty sure needs to be changed:

```
pid = fork();

    if (pid){      
        wait(&retStatus);
    }

    else {
        if( execvp(args[0], args)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(127);
        }
    }
```

Here is all of my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1<<16
#define ARRAY_SIZE 1<<16

static void parseCmdArgs(char *buffer, char** cmdArgs, 
                size_t cmdArgsSize, size_t *nargs)
{
    char *bufCmdArgs[cmdArgsSize]; 
    char **temp;
    char *buf;
    size_t n, p;

    cmdArgs[0] = buf = bufCmdArgs[0] = buffer;  

    for(temp=bufCmdArgs; (*temp=strsep(&buf, " \n\t")) != NULL ;){
        if ((*temp != '\0') && (++temp >= &bufCmdArgs[cmdArgsSize]))
            break;
    }

    for (p=n=0; bufCmdArgs[n]!=NULL; n++){
        if(strlen(bufCmdArgs[n])>0)
            cmdArgs[p++]=bufCmdArgs[n];
    }

    *nargs=p;
    cmdArgs[p]=NULL;
}
  //int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]){
int main(void)
{
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char *args[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int retStatus;
    size_t nargs;
    pid_t pid;

    printf("$dummyshell\n");
    while(1){

        printf("> ");
        fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
        parseCmdArgs(buffer, args, ARRAY_SIZE, &nargs); 


        if (nargs==0)
            continue;

        if (!strcmp(args[0], "help"))
        {
            printf("cat                    cd (absolute path references only\n");
            printf("exit\n");
            printf("help                   history\n");
            printf("jobs                   kill\n");
            printf("ls                     more\n");
            printf("ps                     pwd\n");
            continue;
        }

        if (!strcmp(args[0], "exit" ))
            exit(0);

    pid = fork();

        if (pid){      
            wait(&retStatus);
        }

        else {
            if( execvp(args[0], args)) {
          fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
                exit(127);
            }
        }
    /*  pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
      setpgrp();
    else if (pid)
      pid = wait(&retStatus);
    else {
      if (execvp(args[0], args)){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(127);
      }
      }*/

    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What actually you need is a daemon..

Comment: Are you sure?  How do I implement a daemon?

Comment: you can search for a simple daemon example.. [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/02/c-daemon-process/) is one